# Set Go Glide in Docker

Tags: docker, go, atom-editor, development-environment, glide-golang

I am building an app with Go and Glide in docker. I also have to use reflex to trigger the compiling automatically.

I can not figure out how to make Glide work out with docker.

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.8.1-alpine

ENV GOBINARIES /go/bin
ENV BUILDPATH /code
ENV REFLEXURL=http://s3.amazonaws.com/wbm-raff/bin/reflex1.8a
ENV REFLEXSHA=19bdbbb68c869f85ee22a6b7fa9c73f8e5b46d0fe7a73df37e028555a6ba03e8

WORKDIR $GOBINARIES
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN wget -q "$REFLEXURL" -O reflex
RUN chmod +x /go/bin/reflex

ENV TOOLS /go/_tools

RUN mkdir -p $BUILDPATH
ENV PORT 5000
EXPOSE $PORT

RUN mkdir -p $TOOLS
ADD build.sh $TOOLS
ADD reflex.conf $TOOLS
RUN chown root $TOOLS/build.sh
RUN chmod +x $TOOLS/build.sh

WORKDIR $BUILDPATH
CMD ["reflex","-c","/go/_tools/reflex.conf"]
```

build.sh

```
set -e
echo "[build.sh:building binary]"
cd $BUILDPATH
glide install -s -v
go build -o /servicebin && rm -rf /tmp/*
echo "[build.sh:launching binary]"
/servicebin
```

reflex.conf

```
-sr '\.build$' -- sh -c '/go/_tools/build.sh'
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  logen:
    build:
      context: ./Docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
    - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
    - .:/code
```

Atom on-save plugin configuration file

```
[
  {
    "srcDir": ".",
    "destDir": ".",
    "files": "**/*.go",
    "command": "echo $(date) - ${srcFile} > .build"
  }
]
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
  "github.com/astaxie/beego"
)

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello world!1")
}

func main() {
    log.SetOutput(os.Stdout)

    port := ":" + os.Getenv("PORT")
    http.HandleFunc("/", hello)

    log.Printf("\n Application is listening on %v\n", port)

    http.ListenAndServe(port, nil)
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to add command to install glide before running build.sh in your dockerfile...

Comment: I replied you below

Comment: My Dockerfile is inside a folder. Maybe the shell in docker can not reach the outside files? like glide.lock and glide.yaml?

Comment: RUN glide install -s cause  `/go/_tools/build.sh: line 6: glide: Permission denied`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I do not need to install Glide in the container! Just reflect the vendor folder in host machine to $GOPATH/src in docker-compose.yml. Then the compile will be ok.

```
version: '3'
services:
  logen:
    build:
      context: ./Docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
    - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
    - .:/code
    - ./vendor:/go/src
```